# How to create column that identifies another column where the row values change?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame in R with some columns with numeric values. I want to identify the columns that have a row value change at a certain point. For example:

```
 A B C D E
 0 6 0 0 0
 0 6 0 1 -5
 0 0 0 2 4
 4 0 0 2 -1
```

I want to identify, for the negative rows in column E, do A, B, C, or D have a row value change from the previous row? So for the -5 in column E, the column that I'd want to identify is D, because its row value changes from 0 to 1, and for the -1 in column E I'd want to identify column A. Is there a way to create another column that identifies A,B,C, or D as the row change column? Thank you in advance

Comment: is it possible to have 2 columns changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could create a difference matrix for the first 4 columns (using your data frame `df`):

```
df_diff <- rbind(0, diff(as.matrix(df[1:4])))
```

Which would give you:

```
     A  B C D
[1,] 0  0 0 0
[2,] 0  0 0 1
[3,] 0 -6 0 1
[4,] 4  0 0 0
```

Then, using `sapply` with an index for your data frame and the different matrix, you could do the following:

```
df$F <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) ifelse(df[i, 5] < 0, 
                                                     names(which(df_diff[i, ] != 0))[1], 
                                                     NA_character_))
```

This will check for negative values in column 5, and for those negative select the first column name found with a difference identified in the different matrix (different of not zero). Otherwise, will put in `NA`. A new column `F` will contain this result.

**Output**

```
  A B C D  E    F
1 0 6 0 0  0 <NA>
2 0 6 0 1 -5    D
3 0 0 0 2  4 <NA>
4 4 0 0 2 -1    A
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(0, 0, 0, 4), B = c(6, 6, 0, 0), C = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), D = c(0, 1, 2, 2), E = c(0, -5, 4, -1), F = c(NA, "D", 
NA, "A")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the most elegant solution but it should work:

```
change <- c()

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$E[i] >= 0) {
    change <- c(change, 'unchanged')
  } else {
    if (df$A[i]!=df$A[i-1]) {
      change <- c(change, 'A')
    } else if (df$B[i]!=df$B[i-1]) {
      change <- c(change, 'B')
    } else if (df$C[i]!=df$C[i-1]) {
      change <- c(change, 'C')
    } else if (df$D[i]!=df$D[i-1]) {
      change <- c(change, 'D')
    }
  }
}

df$Change <- change
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# This is your original dataframe
x <- data.frame(
"A" = c(0,0,0,4), 
"B" = c(6,6,0,0),
"C" = c(0,0,0,0),
"D" = c(0,1,2,2),
"E" = c(0,-5,0,-1))

# Finding the differences with previous row
new_x = data.frame(
"A" = c(0, abs(diff(x$A))),
"B" = c(0, abs(diff(x$B))),
"C" = c(0, abs(diff(x$C))),
"D" = c(0, abs(diff(x$D))),
"E" = x$E)

# max.col gives the position of column that is max.
new_x$R = names(new_x)[max.col(new_x[,1:4], "first")]
# filter out only rows where E is -ve
new_x[new_x$E<0,"R"]
```